# Screen Options button doesn't show up in "Edit Post" Screen

Tags: wordpress, revision

[image]

I just installed WordPress and learning the tutorial. I'm learning the "Revision", the teacher said to show it click the "Screen Options" button in the right corner of edit post but i don't have it. Can you show me how to fix this? Anyway, I'm using Wordpress 5.0

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in your functions.php file.

```
add_filter('screen_options_show_screen', '__return_true');
```

Comment: I added this line to every `functions.php` i got in my website but it doesn't work! Any way i'm using **WordPress 5.0**. I switched back to **WordPress 4.9.8** it works fine but i still want to show it in version 5. Do you know why they don't have "Screen Options" in **Edit Post** Section in **WP5** ?